# UIWebView auto height size

Tags: ios, swift3

I have three web view on one screen, and I need the screens to fit the size of each content. How can I solve it?

I already tried using:

```
let it = productGoal.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "Math.max( document.body.scrollHeight, document.body.offsetHeight, document.documentElement.clientHeight, document.documentElement.scrollHeight, document.documentElement.offsetHeight );")
```

To get the screen size of the webview content, but it always brings me the current screen size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
let it = Double(webView.stringByEvaluatingJavaScript(from: "document.documentElement.scrollHeight") ?? "0")
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay to respond, I was able to test only now. And it worked perfectly, thank you very much.